# Where should I place my Terraria player and world files?

Tags: terraria

Where should I move the player and world files? My computer messed up and my profile isn't working, and my Terraria characters and worlds are all gone. I do have all the files but I'm not sure where to put them. I placed them to the same location in my new profile (windows profile) but when I lauched Terraria nothing was happened. Please help and sorry for language! :)

Answer (score 0):

Into %userprofile%, Documents, My Games, Terraria.
Players should be placed in the "Players" folder, your worlds into "Worlds", config.dat and servers.dat into the Terraria's folder root.